# problems with first attempt at proper modular programming

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with my first attempt at a proper go at modular programming....

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a possible direction as to how to approach the solution to the problem

here is my code and once again it is from Laszlo's Book on computational geometry ..the only thing I did different was break it into smaller pieces and a unit header file

**The Code**

**header.h**

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

// -----Definition of Node Class ----------------------------------

class Node{

    protected:
        Node *_prev;
        Node * _next;
        static int cindex;


    public:
        int index;
        Node(void);
        virtual ~Node(void);
        Node *next(void); // accessor
        Node *prev(void); //accessor
        Node *insert(Node*);
        Node*remove(void);
        void splice (Node*);

    };

// ------ end of definition of Node --------------------
//======================================================
//----------Start of Definition of ListNode class ------

template < class T > class List;


template<class T> class ListNode: public Node {

    public:
        T _val;
        ListNode(T val);
        friend class List<T>;


    };

// ------ End of Definition of ListNode class --------------------
//====================================================++
//----------Start of Definition of List class ------

template<class T> class List {

    private:
        ListNode<T> *header;
        ListNode<T> *win;
        int _length;
    public:
        List(void);
        ~List(void);
        T insert(T);
        T append(T);
        T prepend(T);
        List * append(List*);
        T remove(void);
        void val(T);
        T val(void);
        T next(void);
        T prev(void);
        T first(void);
        T last(void);
        int length(void);
        bool isFirst(void);
        bool isLast(void);
        bool isHead(void);
    };









#endif
```

**node.cpp**

```
    #include "header.h"

    int Node::cindex=0;

    Node::Node(void) :
      _next(this), _prev(this)
      {index=cindex++;}

      Node::~Node(void) {}
      Node* Node:: next(void)
      {
        return _next;  

       } 


     Node* Node::prev(void)
      {
        return _prev;  

       } 

     Node *Node::insert(Node*b){

         b->_next=_next;
         _next->_prev=b;
         b->_prev=this;
         _next=b;
         return b;

         }

    Node*Node::remove(void)
    {

    _prev->_next=_next;
    _next->_prev=_prev;
    _next->_prev=this;
    return this;    
    }
```

**LstNode.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

template <class T> List <T> :: List(void): _length(0)  //constructor for list
{
    header =new ListNode<T>(NULL); //mind you this uses the LIstNode class 
    win=header;

}

template<class T>  List <T>::~ List(void) // weird destructor
{
while (length()>0) {

    first();remove();
    }   
    delete header;

}

template <class T> T List <T> ::insert(T val)
{

win->insert( new ListNode <T> (val));
++_length;
return val;
}

template <class T> T List <T>::prepend(T val)
{   
    header->insert(new ListNode <T> (val));
    ++_length;
    return val;
}   

template <class T> T List <T>::append(T val)
{   
    header->prev()->insert(new ListNode <T> (val));
    ++_length;
    return val;
}

template<class T> List <T>* List <T>::append(List<T>*l)
{
        ListNode<T> *a =(ListNode<T>*)header->prev();
        a->splice(l->header);
        _length+=_length;
        l->header-remove();
        l->_length=0;
        l->win=header;
        return this;

}

template <class T> void List<T>::val(T v)
{
if (win!=header)
        win->_val=v;

}

template <class T> T List<T>::val(void)
{
return win->_val;   
}

template <class T> T List <T>:: next(void)
{
    win=(ListNode <T>*)win->next();
    return win->_val;

}

template <class T> T List <T>:: prev(void)
{
    win=(ListNode <T>*)win->prev();
    return win->_val;

}

template <class T> T List<T>::first(void)
{
win=(ListNode <T>*)header->next();
return win->_val;   

}

template <class T> T List<T>::last(void)
{
win=(ListNode <T>*)header->prev();
return win->_val;   

}

template <class T> int List <T>::length(void)
{
return _length; 
}

template< class T> bool List <T> ::isFirst(void)
{
    return (win==header->next()) &&(_length>0);
}

template< class T> bool List <T> ::isLast(void)
{
    return (win==header->prev()) &&(_length>0);
}

template <class T> bool List <T>::isHead(void)
{
    return (win == header);
}
```

**experiment.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"


int main()
{

List <int> dunder;
dunder.insert(9);
return 0;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**
 I first converted all of these files into object files with the generic command `g++ -o file.cpp` (separately) and then I did this `g++ output.o output2.o ..`
 and this is the error I get :

```
experiment.o: In function `main':
experiment.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `List<int>::List()'
experiment.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `List<int>::insert(int)'
experiment.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `List<int>::~List()'
experiment.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `List<int>::~List()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your template class and its have its definition in the same file. As of right now template class header and definition are not separable.

Comment: so the template class methods cannot be declared outside the header file in which it is defined?

Comment: It can only if you explicitly include that .cpp file in the bottom of the header file. That way both the header and definition are in the same file ultimately. For now I think you should just define it in the header file